# Android Application "Source Not Found" java.lang.runtimeexception

Tags: java, android

I switched from running my app on a phone to a nexus 10 tablet and now it says "unfortunately the application has stopped."

The tablet is running 4.4.2, my target api is set to 19 in the manifest.

When I run it in debug mode I get Source Not Found. I tried clicking edit source lookup path and adding my project and had no luck.

I've looked all over the internet and haven't had any luck solving this problem. Any suggestions would be a big help.

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.looper.video/com.looper.video.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException"

**Edit:**

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.looper.video;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private VideoView video;
    private MediaController ctlr;
    final Uri firstVideoPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.looper.video/" + R.raw.wildlife);
    final Uri secondVideoPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.looper.video/" + R.raw.wildlife1);
    private String videosPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/videos/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        File folder = new File(videosPath);
        File[] customFiles = folder.listFiles();

        List<String> customFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(File file : customFiles) {
            customFileNames.add(file.getName());

        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                 this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, customFileNames);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerCustomFiles);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);


        video = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        ctlr = new MediaController(this);


        final Button firstVideoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstVideoBtn);
        firstVideoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                playFirstVideo();
            }
        });

        final Button secondVideoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secondVideoBtn);
        secondVideoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                playSecondVideo();

            }
        });

    }

    public void playFeatured(View v) {
        try {

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerCustomFiles);
        String strPath = videosPath + spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, strPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Uri path = Uri.parse(videosPath + spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

        video.setVideoPath(strPath);
        ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
        video.setMediaController(ctlr);
        video.requestFocus();
        video.start();

        video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer vmp) {
                playSecondVideo();        
            }
        });

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());


        }

    }

    public void playFirstVideo() {
        video.setVideoURI(firstVideoPath);
        ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
        video.setMediaController(ctlr);
        video.requestFocus();
        video.start();

        video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer vmp) {
                playSecondVideo();        
            }
        });
    }

    public void playSecondVideo() {

        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("schedule", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        String startTime = sp.getString("startTime", "");
        String endTime = sp.getString("endTime", "");
        /*
        //SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        //Date dateStartTime = parser.parse(startTime);
        //Date dateEndTime = parser.parse(endTime);
        Date now = new Date();

        try {
            if (userDate.after(ten) && userDate.before(eighteen)) {

            } 
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // Invalid date was entered
        }


        System.out.println("Now:"+now);
        System.out.println("Start"+startTime);
        System.out.println("End:"+endTime);
        //if(now.before(dateEndTime) && now.after(dateStartTime)){

            //disableAll();
        //} else {
         * 
         */
            video.setVideoURI(secondVideoPath);
            ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
            video.setMediaController(ctlr);
            video.requestFocus();
            video.start();

            video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer vmp) {
                        playSecondVideo();        
                    }

            });
        //}

    }

    public void admin(View view) 
    {
        //MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

        //final String password = db.getUser(7).getPassword();
        //db.close();



        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText pass = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(pass);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String value = pass.getText().toString().trim();

                SharedPreferences sp1 = getSharedPreferences("Login", 0);
                //String username = sp1.getString("UserName", "");       
                String password = sp1.getString("Password", "");

                if(value.equals(password)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),Admin.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), password + " " + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alert.show();   
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void disableAll(){
        Button firstVideoBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.firstVideoBtn);
        firstVideoBtn.setEnabled(false);
        Button secondVideoBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.secondVideoBtn);
        secondVideoBtn.setEnabled(false);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerCustomFiles);
        spinner.setEnabled(false);
        Button btnPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlayFeatured);
        btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        videoView.setEnabled(false);
    }
  }
```

**Full logcat:**

```
    D/dalvikvm(2817): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 58K, 4% free 3441K/3568K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
    10-08 15:23:17.965: D/dalvikvm(2817): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3505K/3632K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
    10-08 15:23:17.975: I/dalvikvm-heap(2817): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.739MB for 5515216-byte allocation
    10-08 15:23:17.985: D/dalvikvm(2817): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 8891K/9020K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
    10-08 15:23:18.055: D/AndroidRuntime(2817): Shutting down VM
    10-08 15:23:18.055: W/dalvikvm(2817): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4155eba8)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817): Process: com.looper.video, PID: 2817
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.looper.video/com.looper.video.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at com.looper.video.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    10-08 15:23:18.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: It looks more like the NullPointerException is the problem, can you post the full error message as well as the code for your MainActivity?

Comment: please, post your logcat completely.

Comment: It looks like the error comes from this line `customFileNames.add(file.getName());` in the for loop of your onCreate method.

Comment: No. The error actually comes from `for(File file : customFiles)` which means that customFiles is null.

Comment: Where is line 52 of MainActivity.java?

Comment: Please post the entirety of your MainActivity.java including the imports at the beginning.  Also, can you post your activity_main.xml file?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice if you didn't edited the post and removed the imports you would know where that line is.

Comment: @PedroOliveira I can't count that high.